# Reuse WITH table definition across multiple code blocks

Tags: t-sql

I have a set of tables that contain history, with the latest record marked as current = 1 and deleted = 0.

I want to run queries using the current data only, which i want to define once, and then use in multiple places.

I defined a set of table using a WITH statement.  I then created a set of blocks to create temp tables.

```
DECLARE
          @first_order_date nvarchar(50) = '2018-01-01'
         ,@second_order_date nvarchar(50) = '2019-01-01'

;WITH
customer AS (SELECT customer_id FROM d_customer WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0),
supplier AS (SELECT supplier_id FROM d_supplier WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0),
orderz AS (SELECT order_id, customer_id, supplier_id, order_date FROM d_order WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0)

BEGIN
     SELECT 
          * 
     INTO
          #first_order
     FROM 
          orderz
     WHERE
          order_date >= @first_order_date
END

BEGIN
     SELECT 
          * 
     INTO
          #second_order
     FROM 
          orderz
     WHERE
          order_date >= @second_order_date
END
```

I get error: invalid object name 'orderz'.

If a put the code:

```
WITH orderz AS (SELECT order_id, customer_id, supplier_id, order_date FROM d_order WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0)
```

Within each block i.e:

```
BEGIN
     WITH 
          orderz AS (SELECT 
                         order_id, 
                         customer_id, 
                         supplier_id, 
                         order_date            
                    FROM
                         d_order
                    WHERE 
                         current = 1 AND 
                    deleted = 0)
     SELECT 
          * 
     INTO
          #first_order
     FROM 
          orderz
     WHERE
          order_date >= @first_order_date
END
BEGIN
     WITH 
          orderz AS (SELECT 
                         order_id, 
                         customer_id, 
                         supplier_id, 
                         order_date 
                    FROM
                         d_order         
                    WHERE 
                         current = 1 AND 
                    deleted = 0)
     SELECT 
          * 
     INTO
          #second_order
     FROM 
          orderz
     WHERE
          order_date >= @second_order_date
END
```

This works, but as you can see I have had to add the WITH statement in multiple places and is therefore hard to maintain.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: WITH as clause must be used as query immediately as per syntax , you cannot create multiple WITH as and used them later on.

Comment: You could create a _table-valued function_ (TVF) and then reference that multiple times.There may be some substantial performance penalties. A CTE and the statement that uses it are handled as a single entity by the query optimizer. A TVF is separate from the statement that uses it. You could also combine the queries and use a `case` expression to generate a new column identifying each row as a "first" or "second" date (or both). It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish, row counts, ... .

Answer (score 3):

A [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can only be used within the scope of a single statement:

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement.

What you can do, however, is either create views instead, or inline table valued functions.

Using views:

```
CREATE VIEW customer AS 
    SELECT customer_id 
    FROM d_customer 
    WHERE current = 1 
    AND deleted = 0
GO

CREATE VIEW supplier AS 
    SELECT supplier_id 
    FROM d_supplier 
    WHERE current = 1 
    AND deleted = 0
GO

CREATE VIEW orderz AS 
    SELECT order_id, customer_id, supplier_id, order_date 
    FROM d_order 
    WHERE current = 1 
    AND deleted = 0
GO
```

Using inline table valued functions might have a performance benefit over views, depending on the usage. Here's an example (Note: the parenthesis are required):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.customer()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT customer_id 
    FROM d_customer 
    WHERE current = 1 
    AND deleted = 0
);

GO
```

And you use it like this: (Note: the parenthesis are required here as well)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.customer()
```

Comment: Can these be created in tempdb?

Comment: Why would you want that? tempdb is a system database, as a rule of thumb, you shouldn't mess with system databases.

Answer (score 0):

Since a CTE needs to be used in the scope of a single statement, it is not possible to call it in two separate select statements. 
Have you considered replacing the CTEs with more temporary table definitions?

```
DECLARE
      @first_order_date nvarchar(50) = '2018-01-01'
     ,@second_order_date nvarchar(50) = '2019-01-01'


 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #customer;
 SELECT customer_id into #customer FROM d_customer WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0;
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #supplier
 SELECT supplier_id INTO #supplier FROM d_supplier WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0;
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #orderz;
 SELECT order_id, customer_id, supplier_id, order_date INTO #orderz FROM d_order 
 WHERE current = 1 AND deleted = 0;

BEGIN
 SELECT 
      * 
 INTO
      #first_order
 FROM 
      #orderz
 WHERE
      order_date >= @first_order_date
END

BEGIN
  SELECT * 
 INTO
      #second_order
 FROM 
      #orderz
 WHERE
      order_date >= @second_order_date
 END`
```

With this solution you define #orderz once and because it gets dropped first everytime you run the script you will only be using current data.